# Emulate 4k display in chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

So i found that i could add devices in chrome dev tools.

(press cmd+shift+m while dev tools are open, then on the top bar klick on 'Responsive' and 'Edit...')

Did anyone get useful settings (for an 1080p monitor) here?

[image: Chrome dev tools: Emulated Devices]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No need to add an device. Just klick on the bar below 
[image: responsive bar]

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, been working with Chrome's dev tools for ages but never noticed this.